# Need help on entity framework projections

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have two entities: Customer and address

```
CUSTOMER
---------
Id
Name
Addresses

ADDRESS
---------
Id
CustomerId
Street
City
Country
IsPrimaryAddress
```

Customer can have multiple address but only one primary address.
I need to get a list of customers along with its primary address only. How can i get it with a single call to the database?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a new type that is not an entity and return this from your query:

```
using (var db = new YourDbContext())
{
    var results = 
        from customer in db.Customers
        let primaryAddress = customer.Addresses.Single(a => a.IsPrimaryAddress)
        select new CustomerQueryResult
        {
            Id = customer.Id,
            Name = customer.Name,
            Address = primaryAddress
        };

    return results.ToArray();
}
```